# Hibernate is auto updating my entity, even if error occurred in between

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions, rollback

I have one entity named "Program". I am doing some operation with this entity. But I don't know how or why, my entity gets updated even I am getting exception. So can anyone help me out to fix this problem.

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/testtransaction/{tid}")
public ApiResponse testTransaction(@PathVariable("tid") String tid){
     return gsService.testTransaction(tid);
}
```

Service

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ApiResponse testTransaction(String tid) {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
    try {
        Optional<Program> existProgram = programRepository.findById(tid);
        if(existProgram.isPresent()) {
            //For testing I am setting random value
            existProgram.get().setProgramName("tid_"+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)));
                
            try {
                int err = 8/0;
            }catch(Exception e) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException(Program.class, "prog cd", tid);
            }
                    
            programRepository.save(existProgram.get());
            apiResponse.setData("Success");
        }else {
            apiResponse.setError("Program details not found for "+tid);
            apiResponse.setStatusCode(500);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        apiResponse.setError("Something went wrong while testing.");
        apiResponse.setStatusCode(500);
        return apiResponse;
    }
    return apiResponse;
}
```

Entity

```
package com.edudb.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL)
@Table(name = "PROGRAM_MASTER")
public class Program {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROGRAM_CD")
    private String programCd;
    
    @Column(name = "PROGRAM_NAME")
    @Size(min=1, max=100, message = "Minimum 1 & maximum 100 characters only")
    private String programName;
    
    @Column(name="ENT_BY")
    @Size(min=1, max=12, message = "Minimum 1 & maximum 12 characters only")
    private String entBy;
    
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd MMM yyyy")  
    @Column(name = "ENT_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date entDt;
    
    @Column(name="DEL_BY")
    @Size(min=1, max=12, message = "Minimum 1 & maximum 12 characters only")
    private String delBy;
    
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd MMM yyyy")  
    @Column(name = "DEL_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date delDt;
    
    @Column(name="LAST_UPDT_BY")
    @Size(min=1, max=12, message = "Minimum 1 & maximum 12 characters only")
    private String updtBy;
    
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd MMM yyyy")  
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDT_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date updtDt;
}
```

Response what I am getting in postman

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Something went wrong while testing."
}
```

Spring boot log

```
2021-11-23 10:34:20 DEBUG --- origin:null
 : com.datanet.filter.SimpleCorsFilter     2021-11-23 10:34:20 DEBUG --- 
    select
        program0_.program_cd as program_cd1_83_0_,
        program0_.del_by as del_by2_83_0_,
        program0_.del_dt as del_dt3_83_0_,
        program0_.ent_by as ent_by4_83_0_,
        program0_.ent_dt as ent_dt5_83_0_,
        program0_.program_name as program_name6_83_0_,
        program0_.last_updt_by as last_updt_by7_83_0_,
        program0_.last_updt_dt as last_updt_dt8_83_0_ 
    from
        program_master program0_ 
    where
        program0_.program_cd=?
 : org.hibernate.SQL                       2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [demo]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 DEBUG --- 
    update
        program_master 
    set
        del_by=?,
        del_dt=?,
        ent_by=?,
        ent_dt=?,
        program_name=?,
        last_updt_by=?,
        last_updt_dt=? 
    where
        program_cd=?
 : org.hibernate.SQL                       2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [john]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - [2021-10-06]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [peter]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [4] as [DATE] - [2021-10-06]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [tid_52.0]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [john]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [7] as [DATE] - [2021-10-06]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder2021-11-23 10:34:20 TRACE --- binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [demo]
 : ibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
```

So if anyone has faced this problem previously, can please help me to fix this :(

Comment: Can you display `stack trace` inside your ide

Comment: Your code is wrong. There is never an exception... At least for the transaction as you are catching everything, the transaction never sees it and will just commit. So basically you made the `@Transactional` you have useless. You should let the exception bubble up so that the transaction interceptor can act accordingly.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I have already added stack trace of IDE as "Spring boot log"

Comment: @M.Deinum My code is correct. The thing is if I changes anything with Entiry data before exception, then only I am facing this issue. Otherwise my code work prefectly. Note: If I update the entity before exception, hibernate itself fire update queries.

Comment: remove the try-catch inside the @Transactional and handle the exception using global exception handler

Comment: Thanks for your valuable replies; but I have found something which solves my problem. TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();

Comment: No your code isn't correct, your code breaks proper transaction management. Which you can only solve by  manually manage the transaction which is your workaround not a solution. Your code shouldn't return an `ApiResponse` (looks also web related) but just throw the exception. You should then have an exception handler preparing the correct `ApiResponse` based on the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

By adding following lines of code in catch or finally or at the end of fucntion, hibernate rollback the entire transaction.

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```